# Should I use WITH instead of a JOIN on a table with a lot of data?

Tags: mariadb

I have a MariaDB table which contains a lot of metadata and is very big in terms of bytes.

I have columns A, B in that table a long with other columns.

I would like to join that table with another table (stuff) in order to get column C from it.

So I have something like:

```
SELECT metadata.A, metadata.B, stuff.C FROM metadata JOIN
stuff on metadata.D = stuff.D
```

This query takes a very long time *sometimes*, I suspect its because (AFAIK, please correct me if Im wrong) that `JOIN` stores the result of the join in some side table and because metadata table is very big it has to copy a lot of data even though I dont use it, so I thought about optimizing it with `WITH` as follows:

```
WITH m as (SELECT A,B,D FROM metadata),
     s as (SELECT C,D FROM stuff)
SELECT * FROM m JOIN s ON m.D = s.D;
```

The execution plan is the same (using `EXPLAIN`) but I think it will be faster since the side tables that will be created by WITH (again AFAIK WITH also creates side tables, please correct me if Im wrong) will be smaller and only contain the needed data.

Is my logic correct? Is there some way I can test that in MariaDB?

Comment: I removed the mysql tag, because you said you are using mariadb. The implementation of CTE in MariaDB dates back to 10.2.1 (2016-07-04), whereas MySQL introduced their support for CTE in 8.0.1 (2017-04-10).

Answer (score 1):

More likely, there is some form of cache speeding up one query or the other.

The Query cache is usually recognizable by a query time that is only about 1ms.  It can be turned off via `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to get a timing to compare against.

The other likely cache is the buffer_pool.  Data is read from disk into the buffer_pool *unless* it is already there.  The simple workaround for strange timings is to run the query twice and take the second 'time'.

Your hypothesis that `WITH` creates 'small' temp tables falls apart because of the work that is needed to read the original tables is the same with or without `WITH`.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the two tables.  There are a couple of datatype issues that *may* be involved -- big TEXTs or BLOBs.

The newly-added `WITH` opens up the possibility of recursive `CTEs` (and other things).  And it provides a way to materialize a temp table that is used more than once.  Neither of those applies in your query, so I would not expect any performance improvement.

Comment: About the part of needing the same work to read the table, with `WITH` it only reads 3 columns to create the temp table while with the JOIN it needs to read all of the data to create a temp table with it, doesnt it?
No Blobs, there is one TEXT but its not big, will provide a `show create table` soon.